# Is it safe to delete .ethash folder and its contents from system?

Tags: synchronization, installation

As a first foray in to Ethereum I started downloading the Ethereum Wallet for OSX from https://www.ethereum.org/.  When I realised how long it was going to take to download the blockchain I killed the download and removed the application.  Looking around my Mac I see that I have a directory `~/.ethash`, and that it has a file named `full-R23-0000000000000000.`  This file is about 1GB.

Am I right in thinking that this is the blockchain (or the part that I downloaded, at least)?  And can I safely delete it if I don't want to use Ethereum Wallet on this machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This file is part of the Ethereum mining computation and can be safely deleted from your machine. It is not part of the blockchain, but just a by-product of the blockchain.

If you do ever want to run the Ethereum Wallet on your machine again, the Ethereum software will generate this file if required.

Answer (score 5):

### Yes, you can delete that file.

#### 1. What is `.ethash`

> [Ethash](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash) is Ethereum‘s Proof of Work hashing algorithm. The algorithm is GPU memory intensive to discourage CPU mining and future development of ASIC‘s.

#### 2. Intentions.

**IO saturation:** The algorithm should consume nearly the entire available memory access bandwidth (this is a strategy toward achieving ASIC resistance, the argument being that commodity RAM, especially in GPUs, is much closer to the theoretical optimum than commodity computing capacity)

**GPU friendliness:** We try to make it as easy as possible to mine with GPUs. Targeting CPUs is almost certainly impossible, as potential specialization gains are too great, and there do exist criticisms of CPU-friendly algorithms that they are vulnerable to botnets, so we target GPUs as a compromise.

**Light client verifiability:** a light client should be able to verify a round of mining in under 0.01 seconds on a desktop in C, and under 0.1 seconds in Python or Javascript, with at most 1 MB of memory (but exponentially increasing)

**Light client slowdown**: the process of running the algorithm with a light client should be much slower than the process with a full client, to the point that the light client algorithm is not an economically viable route toward making a mining implementation, including via specialized hardware.
Light client fast startup: a light client should be able to become fully operational and able to verify blocks within 40 seconds in Javascript.

#### The general route that the algorithm takes is as follows:

1. There exists a seed which can be computed for each block by scanning through the block headers up until that point.
2. From the seed, one can compute a 16 MB pseudorandom cache. Light clients store the cache.
3. From the cache, we can generate a 1 GB dataset, with the property that each item in the dataset depends on only a small number of items from the cache. Full clients and miners store the dataset. The dataset grows linearly with time.
4. Mining involves grabbing random slices of the dataset and hashing them together. Verification can be done with low memory by using the cache to regenerate the specific pieces of the dataset that you need, so you only need to store the cache.