# If we reinitialize ethereum blockchain (running using geth) will we loose all the data?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am running private blockchain using geth and my miners has stopped mining the data. A few days back I have removed old files from .ethash folder ... I am just wondering if that could be the reason that my miners are not working anymore.

Also, somewhere I read that I can remove .ethash folder completetly and the restart the blockchain but my concern is if I will restart the chain then will I loose existing data of chain?

Am I right and is there anything I can do?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by re-initialize?

Comment: @StevenV: If I will run this command: "geth init customGenesis.json --datadir chainData"

Answer (score 0):

The ethash folder does not contains any chain data, but cached files for PoW system (here is another questions tha can be useful [delete .ethash folder](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9234/is-it-safe-to-delete-ethash-folder-and-its-contents-from-system).

Using the init command, will not delete any database (as far as I know, init command on an already started BC will not do anything).

If you want to remove the db completely, you can run the command `geth --datadir <data-di> removedb`.